# Toggle state in c# - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, toggle, state

I want to make a function to work in toggle(switch) mode when i press a key and i really can't figure how to do it. I tried lots of ways and only the "RegisterHotKey" method is working fine. But "RegisterHotKey" is overwriting the mapped key from the game and this is not what i need. So i'm trying to use "GetKeyState". The code below it's only working for one position no matter what i change...:

```
private void mw_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    bool sw = (toggle = !toggle);
    int tog = (GetKeyState(Key.Tab)); 

    if ((tog & 1) == 1)
    {
       if (sw)
       {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("go to second position...!");
       }
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("go to first position...!");
    }
}
```

Any idea or suggestion how can i do this ?

Thank you,

Comment: You can declare a  bool as class member variable which represent it's state. And update the toggle the value in key down

Comment: I have this and still not working : public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool toggle = false;
}

Comment: I have used a ToggleButton in the view and bound the 'IsChecked' property to a Boolean in the view model, and you can use the same concept to translate the metaphor to key strokes.  I would be leery of using message boxes inside of an event handler because they can disrupt the keyboard focus!

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by Sergey Alexandrovich Kryukov from CodeProject.

Link: [solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/639080/Toggle-state-in-Csharp-WPF)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    bool toggle;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainWindow.KeyDown += (sender, eventArgs) => { if (eventArgs.Key == Key.F7) toggle = !toggle; };
    }

    private void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (toggle)
        {
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("go to second position...!");
        }
        else
        {
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("go to first position...!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot fix the code indent in here...if someone else can...thank you.